# Question about plasma parameters Wikipedia page

Tags: plasma-physics

I am trying to make sense of the following [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_parameters). Do you know what the charge state $Z$ is? Do you know if there is a table or list somewhere which lists these parameters but in SI units instead of Gaussian units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know what the charge state $Z$ is?

$Z$ is the number of protons in the ions. The charge of each ion is $Ze$.

> Do you know if there is a table or list somewhere which lists these parameters but in SI units instead of Gaussian units?

No, but this [SI/Gaussian Formula Conversion Table](http://www.pgccphy.net/ref/gaussian-conv.pdf) should be helpful.

It is easy to find textbooks on plasma physics that use SI units. (The first one I found by web search did.)

Answer (score 0):

This may have what you're looking for:
https://www.nrl.navy.mil/ppd/content/nrl-plasma-formulary